# Devise mail confirm in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with [mail confirm](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users); make all items without Allowing Unconfirmed Access and in 3 line got error:

> undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email` for

```
1 else
2 match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
3 match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
4 end
5 end
```

Comment: thanks,i forgot this, and maybe you know how to make link to localhost:3000
without domen?

Answer (score 0):

comment out this line in `config/intializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.reconfirmable = true
```

Comment: this is correct originally

Comment: try setting it to false?

Comment: solve this problem with helful comment
 possible duplicate of Undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email' when registering users? –  Eel Lee 1 hour ago

Comment: I miss unconfirmed_email column in db.
add t.reconfirmable in migrations and run rake db:migrate
or if you're using devise >= 2.0
t.string   :unconfirmed_email